# How do I get technical information on my video card? (Model, RAM, Mhz, etc)

Tags: mac, hardware, video-adapter, system-information

I'd like to get as much technical information about my MacOSX's video card as possible... technical details, even serial number if the card has a unique identifier.

I intend to use this information do research what GPU specific commands I can run on a given laptop.

Comment: Have you looked in Apple Menu - About This Mac? From there, I suspect it all depends on the vendor and model as to where to look next?

Comment: `lspci -nn` or something similar from the command line would work

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Click on the Apple icon in the upper left hand corner of your menu bar and select `About This Mac` from the menu.

In the dialog that appears click on the `More Info...` button to bring up the detailed about dialog.

[image]

Click on the `System Report...` button and you'll get a split-window dialog that has hardware components down the left side and details on the right.

[image]

Click on `Graphics/Displays` on the left. Pick a graphics card from the right side and you'll see all the details the system provides about it.

[image]

You can also get to the System Report by running Applications -> Utilities -> System Information.

Comment: Wow you were quick on the graphics.  Can you tell me how you did that?

Comment: I use Skitch: http://evernote.com/skitch/

Answer (score 21):

Select Graphics/Displays from the output of `system_profiler`.

In a mac terminal, type:

`system_profiler SPDisplaysDataType`

The output will show something like this with your card name and details:

```
system_profiler SPDisplaysDataType

Graphics/Displays:

AMD FirePro D500:

  Chipset Model: AMD FirePro D500
  Type: GPU
  Bus: PCIe
  Slot: Slot-2
  PCIe Lane Width: x16
  VRAM (Total): 3072 MB
  Vendor: ATI (0x1002)
  Device ID: 0x679e
  Revision ID: 0x0000
  ROM Revision: 113-C3861J-687
  gMux Version: 4.0.11 [3.2.8]
  EFI Driver Version: 01.00.687
  Displays:
    CS230:
      Resolution: 1920 x 1080
      Pixel Depth: 32-Bit Color (ARGB8888)
      Display Serial Number: 27673034
      Main Display: Yes
      Mirror: Off
      Online: Yes
      Rotation: Supported
    CS230:
      Resolution: 1920 x 1080 @ 60Hz (1080p)
      Pixel Depth: 32-Bit Color (ARGB8888)
      Display Serial Number: 27712034
      Mirror: Off
      Online: Yes
      Rotation: Supported
      Television: Yes

AMD FirePro D500:
```

Comment: Cool. I was wondering if a command line version of System Information existed.

Answer (score 1):

There is a small amount of information in System Information/System Profiler -> Graphics and Displays

If you want more, you will have to take apart your Mac and actually look at the graphics card.

Comment: lol - take it apart. I suppose some learn that way, but a link to an ifixit.com takeapart might be much easier than opening your iMac - especially the newer ones where dust behind the screen is hard to clear for most DIY repairers.

Comment: A ifixit teardown wouldn't have the OP's serial number, and the OP didn't mention which model his Mac was.

Comment: It's not clear the OP is looking to ask a general question or wants someone to do the work for a specific Mac. Both answers are of course welcome to a vague question. Luckily, we have questions and answers on how to take a serial number and determine the model of hardware for people with that question.